# Accessing objects in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to get age object's value with the name object on following mentioned AngularJS expression:

```
{{{name: 'Jhon', age: '15' }.name}}
```

Comment: [{ name: 'John', age: 15 }]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
<div>
  Name = {{ {name: 'Jhon', age: '15' }.name | json }}
</div>
<div>
  Age = {{ {name: 'Jhon', age: '15' }.age | json }}
</div>
```

Have a look at the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/59mk1gu7/).

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, but with a slight modification Eg.

```
({key : 1}).key
```

But you cannot use this object elsewhere. So there is no point in creating such objects unless you are referring via a variable.